# jQuery Datatables refresh view

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm using jQuery DataTables and adding rows after a successful insert to a DB. How can I force a refresh of the table? I have checked on docs but found only how to refresh if data is loaded with Ajax. I'm adding to the tbody client side.

Comment: I guess it depends upon how you're adding your new row? If you're adding it by adding the data via markup (adding a `<tr>` and one or more `<td>`s) then it should show but won't be registered with DataTables and thus won't be searchable, orderable and what have you. If you're adding it using the `table.row.add(...row data...)`, method then all is good, just add `draw()` to the end so: `table.row.add(...row data...).draw()`. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using legacy datatable

```
      tableObj.fnClearTable();
      tableObj.fnAddData(data);
      tableObj.fnDraw();
```

also `fnRedraw()`, If you want to redraw the table

If you are using new Datatable then [this](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw()) may help you.

```
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();
    $('#myFilter').on( 'keyup', function () {
        table
            .search( this.value )
            .draw();
    } );


var table = $('#example').DataTable();

// Sort by column 1 and then re-draw
table
    .order( [[ 1, 'asc' ]] )
    .draw( false );
```